# Can this be called recursive?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function move() {

    pos = pos+1;

    t = setTimeout(move, 100); 
}
```

Can that be called recursive? If yes, could you provide any reference?

Comment: Don't put quotes around the function name in setTimeout. It definitely wouldn't be recursive because the function would never be called, just referenced :-)

Comment: At best it could be called recurring :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the difference between recursion (func_a calls func_a) or indirect recursion (func_a calls func_b calls func_a) is that using a timer for repetitive calls will (decoupling) not grow the stack and previous state is lost.

Comment: This is true in tail-recursion in a language that performs tail-call optimization. In Scheme: `(define (move) (set! pos (+ pos 1)) (move))` will not grow the stack either, but it certainly seems to be recursive. As I said in my answer, there isn't really a hard line between something that's recursive and something that's not.

Answer (score 3):

No. The function is called by an external source (the timer), so it is not recursive.

Comment: No, it *sets* the timer. And then it exits.

Comment: This is definitely not recursive.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your definition of recursive, but I would say this is scheduling a callback to be called iteratively, not recursion.

Recursion involves breaking a problem down into smaller, similar problems, until you reach a base case, and then possibly combining the results from those into a solution. There is no "smaller" problem here; it's just scheduling the same callback to happen again after a certain time.

The problem with any sort of hard and fast definition is that recursion can be implemented in terms of iteration, and vice versa.

For instance, is this recursive?

```
function state1() {
    doSomething();
    return "state2";
}

function state2() {
    doSomethingElse();
    return "state1";
}

var state = "state1";
while (true) {
    if (state == "state1") {
        state = state1();
    } else {
        state = state2();
    }
}
```

`state1` and `state1` each cause the other to be called; so in one sense, that's mutual recursion. It's driven by an iterative loop though, so it could also be considered iteration.

In a language that supports tail-call optimization, the same effect could be had by the two functions recursively calling each other (in fact, even in a language without tail-call optimization, you could do it, but you would run out of stack space very quickly):

```
function state1() {
    doSomething();
    state2();
}

function state2() {
    doSomething();
    state1();
}
```

So, the question really becomes, how do you distinguish whether something is recursive? Does the fact that one function causes itself to be called again make it recursive?

Comment: I don't think that your example shows recursion, looks like a simple loop with alternating calls. There is no state as it would be required for tree traversal, either your state is on stack or explicit handled.

Comment: In a language with tail-call optimization (such as Scheme), however, they are basically equivalent; the second example would not actually have any state on the stack either, as tail calls allow you to drop the previous stack frame. So, in a language with TCO, does the tail-recursive solution suddenly stop being recursive because it doesn't grow the stack?

Comment: You made me learn about tail-call in my opinion this is unneccesary use of recursion like traversing of a list, if and only if you have no need to come back where you were earlier (this would require the state). BTW the question is tagged as javascript related.

Comment: I was not sure it is recursive or not, thats why I only tagged as javascript. thanks a lot for explantions for all anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The code in question is not recursion - as the code is being called externally, not as part of a cyclic code-path back to the same method call.

Wikipedia has a great page about recursion here: [Wikipedia: Recursion (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 2):

I would call it an inifite loop with a delay.

When the function returns, it does not get back into a previous call instance of itself, hence there is no deep "call stack" as it typically is in recursions.

Comment: What if function contained `if(pos==100) dosomething()` ? I don't think he's asking it specifically for the given code.

Comment: what I see as a typical recursion is when you can say "this task is done when these sub-tasks are done". However, in this case the code performs what it should and then "calls itself", but without subtasking - this is a loop. The code might as well be `while(true) {move()} function move(){pos++}`

Answer (score 1):

So, here f1 ("move") is calling f2 ("setTimeout"), which in turn calls f1 again. Hmm.. this is a recursion if f2 is a callback function. But, if f2 is setting some property, like a "timeout". This isn't recursion.

Answer (score 1):

technically it could be...

```
function move() {

    var $this = this;

    pos = pos+1;

    t = setTimeout($this, 100);
}
```

but I see no reason why you'd wanna do this.  and if you *really* wanna get silly (and lock up your browser's thread):

```
function move() {

    var now = +new Date;

    pos = pos+1;

    while( ( +new Date - now ) <= 100 ){ }

    move( );
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks, I just put cleaned up example at my post, because I don't want people get attention on unrelated codes.

Answer (score 0):

No, the function does not call itself. It would be recursive if the function called itself within the body of move.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is .. but it can be called as Indirect recursion ..

example for Direct recursion would be something like this:

```
    function factorial (n)
  {
        if(n==0)
   { 
        return(1);
   }

     return (n * factorial (n-1) ); 
  }
```

likewise others said .. the function calling itself ..

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't call `move`. It just sets up `move` to be called when the timeout expires and returns.